# Objective C: Creating rotated Image inside square?

Tags: objective-c, image, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, core-image

For an arduino drawing robot i want to rotate an image by 45 degrees  in an iOS app, so that the new (rotated image) is inside a white box. Imagine the blue rectangle in the picture was the original image, and the image. As you can see it is rotated an inside a white square. How could I do this? It is important not only to have a rotated image, or a rotated image which has a white box *behind* it on the screen. It actually has to be a new image, so that if i get the color of pixel (1,1) it is white.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this with having a white UIView superview, and blue UIView subview. And then do:

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4);
superview.bound = subview.frame;
```

I think it should work.